# Error during Helm Chart install: failed parsing

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install a Helm Chart using this command

`helm install chartName --dry-run -f "values.yaml" --set noProxy="127.0.0.1,localhost" myChart`

and getting the following error

> Error: failed parsing --set data: key "localhost" has no value

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turned out that this `--set noProxy="127.0.0.1,localhost"` was causing the issue.

The `,` need to be escaped using `\,`.

The following command worked.

`helm install chartName --set noProxy="127.0.0.1\,localhost" myChart`

As the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) specify

> Sometimes you need to use special characters in your `--set` lines. You can use a backslash to escape the characters; `--set name=value1\,value2` will become: `name: "value1,value2"`